# Qt5: Drag and Drop when using QSortFilterProxyModel

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, qt5, qsortfilterproxymodel

I have a model that is sub-classed from `QAbstractListModel` that has different Listviews that are filtered using a sub-classed QSortFilterProxyModel for each view. The data in the view can be sorted when the user clicks a sort button.

I implemented the drag and drop inside the QSortFilterProxyModel, to change the state of the data when it is dropped into a new Listview. This works fine, however, manually sorting the items within a listview causes all other listview displaying the same data to be sorted as well, which is not what I want.

Example, View 1 shows all participants, view 2 shows participants that are active. When dragged from view 1 to view 2, the participant becomes active. If I manually sort the participants, the index of participants that are active also get sorted. This does however not happen if I automatically sort them using `proxyModel->sort()` method.

How can I manually rearrange the data in the proxy model without changing the index in the source model?

Example code:

```
MySortFilterProxyModel::MySortFilterProxyModel(bool active, QObject *parent ) :
QSortFilterProxyModel( parent ),
m_filter( "" ), 
m_active(active)
{
    setDynamicSortFilter( false );
}

void MySortFilterProxyModel::setFilter( QString filter )
{
   m_filter = filter;
   invalidateFilter();
}

Qt::ItemFlags MySortFilterProxyModel::flags( const QModelIndex &index ) const
{
    if( index.isValid() )
    {
        return ( QSortFilterProxyModel::flags( index ) | Qt::ItemIsDragEnabled |  Qt::ItemIsEditable );
    }

    return Qt::ItemIsDropEnabled |  QSortFilterProxyModel::flags( index );
 }

bool MySortFilterProxyModel::dropMimeData( const QMimeData *data, Qt::DropAction action, int row, int column, const QModelIndex &parent )
 {


     if( !data->hasFormat( dataModel::dataMimeType() ) )
     {
        return false;
     }

     if( action == Qt::IgnoreAction )
     {
        return true;
     }

     if( column > 0 )
     {
        return false;
     }

    QByteArray encodeData = data->data(dataModel::dataMimeType());
    QDataStream stream( &encodeData, QIODevice::ReadOnly );

    while( !stream.atEnd() )
    {
      DataRecord *dr = new DataRecord();
      stream >> dr;

      dr->setActive( m_active );

      // AddData method in the dataModel removes duplicate rows and inserts the data into the correct row.
      qobject_cast< DataModel * >( sourceModel() )->addData( fdr, parent.row() ); 

   }
   return true;
}
```

Edit addData() There is propably a better way to do this:

```
void DataModel::addData( DataRecord *dr, int row )
{
   int i =0;
   for( auto const& itr : m_dataRecords )
   {
       if( itr->getUniqueID() == dr->getUniqueID() )
       {
          break;
       }
       ++i;
   }
   removeRows( i, 1, QModelIndex() ); 

   beginInsertRows( QModelIndex(), row, row );
   m_dataRecords.insert( row, dr );
   endInsertRows();
  }
```

In the DataModel I also implement the following methods:

```
 QVariant data( const QModelIndex &index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole ) const override;

 bool setData( const QModelIndex & index, const QVariant & value, int role=Qt::EditRole );

 bool removeRows( int row, int count, const QModelIndex &parent ) override;

 QMimeData *mimeData( const QModelIndexList &indexes ) const override;

 QStringList mimeTypes() const override;

 int rowCount( const QModelIndex &parent ) const override;

 Qt::DropActions supportedDropActions() const override;
```

Comment: could you show `DataModel::addData`?

Comment: yes, I added it to the question.

Comment: You can't pass `parent.row()` without `mapToSource()` parent and make sure it's valid.

Comment: Ok, but I'm still just updating the indexes of the sourceModel not the proxy model only. I'm wondering if I should implement the mimeData method in the  ProxyModel and keep track of items filtered by the proxy somehow, but this is not obvious to me.

Comment: Unfortunately it's hard to see what's going wrong without seeing the model implementation. QAbstractItemModel subclassing is a minefield

Comment: It would be to big to add all the code for the model here, but I added the content of the header file, maybe there is a method missing I need to implement ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Don't modify `DataModel`

The point of `QSortFilterProxyModel` is that you can provide a new ordering completely independently of any other view on the underlying data. Having that view move the underlying rows around breaks that.

You should instead write a proxy that provides the manual override of ordering, recording where each row should be positioned. This can use the `QSortFilterProxyModel` as its source, which in turn sources from `DataModel`

Comment: I want to have both manual and automatic sorting of the data, e.g. sort data automatically by name in alphabetical order when a button is clicked that calls 'proxyModel->sort()'. That is why 'setDynamicSortFilter(false)' is set and 'lessThan' is already implemented for alphabetical sorting.

Comment: Then you want to have another proxy layer: `DataModel` -> `QSortFilterProxyModel` -> `DragDropReorderProxyModel` where DragDropReorderProxyModel derives QAbstractProxyModel and implements mapFromSource / mapToSource

Comment: That is an excellent idea, thank you. I didn't think you could layer proxies. I will try that.